# Wget: download files to specific directory

Tags: directory, downloads, wget

I have been trying to get wget to download all files to a specific directory. I tried the -O option but I get

/home/user/xml/: Is a directory

This is what I have so far

```
wget -m --user=user --password=pass -r -l1 --no-parent -A.rss ftp://localhost/public_html/
```

I need to download all .rss files from ftp to a specific directory on my secondary server.

Answer (score 8):

use **-P** option.

```
wget -P /home/user/directory_you_want http:url_you_are_downloading_from
```

See more at : [Stackoverflow page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1078524/how-to-specify-the-location-with-wget)

Answer (score 8):

The -P option downloaded all the files to the specific directory however it created 2 new directories inside the target directory.

So the files went into /home/user/xml/192.168.1.1/public_html/

So I tried it with the -P option and the -nd option and it worked the way I needed it to.

The final code looks like this

```
wget -m -nd --user=user --password=password -r -l1 --no-parent -A.rss ftp://localhost/public_html/ -P /home/user/Desktop/xml/
```